# Overloading __iter__ for a Python dataclass with fields containing list of another dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, python-dataclasses

I don't know how to properly overload the iterator for my WholeImage class.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple
from typing import List
import numpy as np

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ActImage:
    __slots__ = ['name', 'action']
    name: np.ndarray
    action: np.ndarray

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(astuple(self))


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class WholeImage:
    __slots__ = ['value', 'x_axis', 'y_axis', 'act']
    value: np.ndarray
    x_axis: List[np.ndarray]
    y_axis: List[np.ndarray]
    act: List[ActImage]

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from (self.value, *self.x_axis, *self.y_axis, *self.act)
```

The way it works now, it returns numpy ndarrays for `value` and elements in `x_axis` and `y_axis` lists, but `ActImage` instances for elements in `act` list.

The way I'd like it to behave, is to return all ndarrays, including the "nested" ones in `ActImage.name` and `ActImage.action`, as in the pseudocode below:

```
def __iter__(self):
   yield from (self.value, *self.x_axis, *self.y_axis, 
               self.act[x].name, self.act[x].action # for x in range(len(act))
               )
```

I'd like to have my code as generic as possible, because new fields (of np.ndarray type too) may be added to ActImage class in the future.